# Wrong Opera Icon in Gnome Shell

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, icons, opera

I am using Opera 11.60 on ArchLinux (64bit) with Gnome3 and KDE4. Since I installed KDE4 last week Gnome3 shows the wrong Icon for Opera in the upper left corner and in the task switcher (alt+tab).

Here is a screenshot of what I see:

[image]

Does anybody know how to get the correct icon and title back, as it also says "opera" instead of "Opera" (capital "O")? 
I already tried reinstalling and removing my `.opera` files but that did not help.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps there is some trouble with recognizing Opera `.desktop` entries - you might want to [create](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Desktop_Entries) one if there are none. `.desktop` entries contains meta information and resources, such as the path to the application executable and the location of the icon used for the application. They are usually located in `/usr/share/applications` so you should take a look there.

To verify if Opera has any `.desktop` entries, do:

```
# pacman -Ql opera | grep *.desktop
```

Comment: There is a desktop file, the icon is shown in the menu if opera is not running, but when I start it the icon is replaced by this generic one. This is quite odd.